# Javascript read checkboxes and save as array

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I have a number of checkboxes formatted like so....

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mybox" value="box1">Box 1</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="mybox" value="box2">Box 2</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="mybox" value="box3">Box 3</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="mybox" value="box4">Box 4</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="mybox" value="box5">Box 5</input>
```

I am attempting to read in which boxes are ticked using javascript and save them as an array,  I am using the following code....

```
  function handleNotifyButtonClick() {
    var type = $.trim($("input[@name='mybox']:checked").each(function()
    {
    add $(this).val() to your array;
    }));
```

But for some reason its not working, can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add $(this).val() to your array;

This is English, not JavaScript.

Try this:

```
var type = [];
$("input[name=mybox]:checked").each(function() {type.push(this.value)});
```

Comment: Perfect, must have been a legacy note I added and never changed!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you do the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), and you have various syntax errors in there. But you're on the right track.

```
function handleNotifyButtonClick() {
    var values = $('input[name="mybox"]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ofopas/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ofopas/1/edit) - The example also corrects the HTML and demonstrates how to use the `label` tag for what I think you were trying to do.

What I've done there:

- Use the attribute equals selector (`name="value"`)
- Use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get a map of the values
- In the iterator function I pass to `map`, I return the value of each checkbox (`this` is the raw DOM object, `value` is entirely reliable cross-browser on `input` elements)
- Use [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get) to turn the returned map (which is a jQuery instance, oddly) into a real array

As a side note, you never use `</input>`. `input` is a [void element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements), it doesn't take a closing tag.